# Position Tapped on screen in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, onclick

Is there any way of getting the pixel location or the (x,y) points on which i clicked on the screen.
Actually I am clicking on the screen and i need to know the x.y position where i clicked. i need to show these points in a popup window on click to the screen
is it possible. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getGlobalX()`, `getGlobalY()` of the [TouchEvent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/TouchEvent.html). Also you can use `getX()` and `getY()` for getting mapped x and y coordinate. See documentation for reference.

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
    int touchXGlobal = event.getGlobalX(1);
    int touchYGlobal = event.getGlobalY(1);
    // rest of codes
```

Comment: its almost working f9 but on the first go its showing -1,-1..??

Comment: The touchEvent(..) method will be invoked more than once for a single tap / touch (from user's perspective). But we need to listen for specific event, e.g. TouchEvent.CLICK, TouchEvent.UNCLICK, TouchGesture.TAP, TouchEvent.UP, TouchEvent.DOWN etc. So use the event that suits best () and use the event data on that case.